# ¿Cómo recorrer una colección con JQuery para mostrar una lista?

Tags: c#, jquery, html5, knockoutjs

Trabajo con `Knockout` y `JQuery` e intento poblar una lista en el `html` por medio de un `each`.

Mi colección, implementada con `knockout` `bp-index.js` es la siguiente:

```
/// <reference path="knockout-2.3.0.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.8.24.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.2.js" />
/// <reference path="ajax-util.js" />
/// <reference path="ko-protected-observable.js" />

$(function () {
    
        var data = [
            { Id: 1, Name: "Ball Handling" },
            { Id: 2, Name: "Passing" },
            { Id: 3, Name: "Shooting" },
            { Id: 4, Name: "Rebounding" },
            { Id: 5, Name: "Transition" },
            { Id: 6, Name: "Defense" },
            { Id: 7, Name: "Team Offense" },
            { Id: 8, Name: "Team Defense" }
    ];

    var viewModel = {
        // data
        tags: ko.observableArray(data),
        tagToAdd: ko.observable(""),

        // behaviors
        addTag: function () {
            this.tags.push({ Name: this.tagToAdd() });
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Este es mi `index.cshtml`:

```
    <div id="tagsList" class="box">
    <div class="box-head">
        <h2 class="left">Tags</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" />
        <button>+ Add</button>

        <div data-bind="template: 'tagsTempl'"></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script id="tagsTempl" type="text/html">
        <ul>
            {{each tags}}
                <li class="tagItem">
                    <span>${Name}</span>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="tag-delete">Delete</a>
                    </div>
           

         </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </script>
    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bp-index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Como resultado, obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: lista con JQuery]

No obstante, lo que espero que salga en la vista es lo siguiente:

```
        Ball Handling
        Passing
        Shooting
        Rebounding
        Transition
        Defense
        Team Offense
        Team Defense
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas llenar una lista `<ul></ul>` desde una matriz empleando Knockoutjs debes emplear `data-binding="foreach: ..."` en tu elemento contenedor. Por ejemplo, tienes una matriz llamada `tags` en tu `viewModel`, entonces puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tags">
    <li class="tagItem">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.Name"></span>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="tag-delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Donde indicas que vas a iterar sobre `tags` y donde `$data` es donde Knocout coloca cada elemento de la iteración, por lo que puedes hacer `$data.Id` para accesar al id del elemento actual o también `$data.Name`.

Ahora bien, si lo que deseas es agregar una `tag` que muestre el `Name` como el valor que contenga tu `<input>` al momento de pulsar sobre el botón `Add+`, lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
var viewModel =
{
    currentTag:  "", // Creas esta variable, a la que pasaremos el valor del input
    ...
```

Y para pasarle el valor del `<input>` es de esta forma `data-bind="value: currentTag"`, tal que así:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" data-bind="value: currentTag" />
```

Por lo que en vez de:

```
this.tags.push({ Name: this.tagToAdd() });
```

Haces:

```
this.tags.push({ Name: this.currentTag });
```

---

Acá te dejo las referencias que consulté:

[KnockJs foreach binding - 1](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

[KnockJs foreach binding - 2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/knockoutjs/foreach-binding.htm)

[KnockJs click binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

[SOen - KnockJs pass data from input to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260556/knockout-how-to-pass-data-bound-input-value-back-to-function-on-click)

Y te dejo además, un ejemplo de código funcional que hice con `jQuery 1.8.2` y `KnockoutJs 2.3.0`:

```js
$(function () {
    
    var data = [
         { Id: 1, Name: "Ball Handling" },
         { Id: 2, Name: "Passing"       },
         { Id: 3, Name: "Shooting"      },
         { Id: 4, Name: "Rebounding"    },
         { Id: 5, Name: "Transition"    },
         { Id: 6, Name: "Defense"       },
         { Id: 7, Name: "Team Offense"  },
         { Id: 8, Name: "Team Defense"  }
    ];

    var viewModel =
    {
        currentTag:   "",
        tags:         ko.observableArray(data),
        addTag:       function ()
        {
            this.tags.push({ Name: this.currentTag });
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="tagsList" class="box">
    <div class="box-head">
        <h2 class="left">Tags</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" data-bind="value: currentTag" />
        <button data-bind="click: addTag">+ Add</button>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: tags">
            <li class="tagItem">
                <span data-bind="text: $data.Name"></span>
                <div>
                     <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a>
                     <a href="#" class="tag-delete">Delete</a>
                 </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```